# How to sum all the same numbers value of List<Object>

Tags: android

I want to sum all the similar numbers values of List of Objects. for example if i've various expense object like `Expense expense = new Expense(date, value)` into a `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();` and add some similar date expenses like

```
list.add(new Expense(23, 700);
list.add(new Expense(23, 900);
list.add(new Expense(23, 700);
list.add(new Expense(24, 500);
list.add(new Expense(29, 500);
```

Now, there is need to add all similar dates expenses of one day. How can i do?

i've tried below listed code

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Expense(23, 700);
list.add(new Expense(23, 900);
list.add(new Expense(23, 700);
list.add(new Expense(24, 500);
list.add(new Expense(29, 500);
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {

 Expense expense1 = (Expense) list.get(i);
 if(expense1.getDate().equals(date)) {
      value += Float.valueOf(expense1.getValue());

 } else{
        value =0f;
        value = Float.valueOf(expense1.getValue());
 }

  date = expense1.getDate();
  Log.d("wdvfd234rsdf", expense1.getDate()+",  "+expense1.getValue());

}
```

```
answer of above example similar as, 
23 date = 1600
24 date = 500
29 date = 500
```

Comment: your code has a lot of syntax error

Comment: could you help me?

Comment: You should use nested for loops.

Comment: could you give me an idea by code?

Comment: you need to sum total expenses incurred in a particular day ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin it would be very simple (you can use it in you android app):

```
fun main() {
    data class Expense(val date: Int, val amount: Int)

    val expenses = listOf(                                                     
        Expense(23, 700),
        Expense(23, 900),
        Expense(23, 700),
        Expense(24, 500),
        Expense(29, 500)
    )

    val dailyExpences = expenses
        .groupBy(Expense::date, Expense::amount)
        .map {Expense(it.key, it.value.sum())}

    println("Daily expences: $dailyExpences")
}
```

Output will be:

```
Daily expences: [Expense(date=23, amount=2300), Expense(date=24, amount=500), Expense(date=29, amount=500)]
```